# Speed up flutter build on Travis CI

Tags: docker, flutter, travis-ci

I've just set up a flutter project and integrated the git repo with Travis. I've noticed the build is fairly slow as it has to clone the flutter repo every time and run `flutter doctor` on it every time too. Is there a way I can speed this up? I've seen you can cache directories but that won't help when running `flutter doctor` every time. It also seems that you cant use docker to achieve this as Travis runs a new virtual image each time.

Is this correct or can I use docker/caching to speed things up?

Heres my `.travis.yaml` if it helps.

```
language: dart
dart:
    - stable
os:
    - linux
sudo: false
addons:
    apt:
    sources:
        - ubuntu-toolchain-r-test
    packages:
        - libstdc++6
        - fonts-droid
install:
    - echo 'Testing SplitterFlutter'
before_script:
    - cd ..
    - git clone https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git -b stable
    - export PATH=`pwd`/flutter/bin:`pwd`/flutter/bin/cache/dart-sdk/bin:$PATH
    - flutter doctor
script:
    - cd $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR
    - echo 'Running linter analysis...'
    - flutter analyze
    - echo 'Running tests...'
    - flutter test
cache:
    directories:
    - $HOME/.pub-cache
```

Is there a way I can cache what is run in the`before_script` so its only run once?

Comment: Hello! Did you take a look at this : https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/